# Conflicting sets of NS records

Tags: domain-name-system, ns-record

When checking the NS records of a domain, depending on which nameserver I query, I either get one set of nameservers, another set of nameservers, or both.

For example, checking with Google DNS, it will randomly either return Rackspace...

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        21599   IN  NS  ns2.rackspace.com.
example.com.        21599   IN  NS  ns.rackspace.com.
```

...or Linode.

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        21599   IN  NS  ns5.linode.com.
example.com.        21599   IN  NS  ns1.linode.com.
example.com.        21599   IN  NS  ns3.linode.com.
example.com.        21599   IN  NS  ns4.linode.com.
example.com.        21599   IN  NS  ns2.linode.com.
```

It gets more bizarre.  If I ask a root nameserver (such as h.gtld-servers.net), or if I use an online domain checker like MX Toolbox, I get **both** sets of nameservers.

```
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
example.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns2.rackspace.com.
example.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns.rackspace.com.
example.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns1.linode.com.
example.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns2.linode.com.
example.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns3.linode.com.
example.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns4.linode.com.
example.com.        172800  IN  NS  ns5.linode.com.
```

I do not have direct control over the domain.  However, those who do have direct control of the domain, which is hosted at Network Solutions, say that they only see the Linode NS records on their end, and it's been more than 48 hours since they last changed DNS settings.

This is quite bizarre, and I've never seen anything quite like it.  How do I even begin to diagnose what might be going wrong here?  How could the root nameserver be getting the Rackspace nameservers if Network Solutions only contains the Linode servers?

Comment: Give us the domain so we can take a look. Was this domain *ever* hosted on Rackspace?

Comment: `How do I even begin to diagnose what might be going wrong here?` - Maybe tell us the domain name so that we could... you know... actually give you insightful feedback.

Comment: My apologies.  The domain is `visitnc.com`.  And yes @ceejayoz, at some point in the past Rackspace was used as the canonical nameserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenny D already gives you the core of the problem to solve (and indeed you should use online troubleshooting tools such as Zonemaster or DNSViz to help you troubleshoot DNS problems), but in short you are in one case of what is called "lame delegation".

This happens when the set of NS is not the same from the parent and the child, where they should match at all time if you do not want to have operational name resolution problems.

In short, for any given name, the parent zone lists the NS records of this name and when you query any of these nameservers they should give you back again the same list of NS records, otherwise the delegation is "lame". In most cases, the recursive nameservers will believe the child set of nameserver instead of the parent one.

Let us `dig`(!) further in your specific case, `visitnc.com` (you should put it in the question, not as comment)

1) At the authoritative nameservers of your parent, that is `.COM`, here is the reply:

```
$ dig @a.gtld-servers.net visitnc.com NS +noall +authority

; <<>> DiG 9.12.0 <<>> @a.gtld-servers.net visitnc.com NS +noall +authority
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
visitnc.com.        172800 IN NS ns2.rackspace.com.
visitnc.com.        172800 IN NS ns.rackspace.com.
visitnc.com.        172800 IN NS ns1.linode.com.
visitnc.com.        172800 IN NS ns2.linode.com.
visitnc.com.        172800 IN NS ns3.linode.com.
visitnc.com.        172800 IN NS ns4.linode.com.
visitnc.com.        172800 IN NS ns5.linode.com.
```

So the parent is telling the world that your domain name is served by 7 authoritative nameservers. Which is nothing wrong per se... if all 7 agree on this list.

2) Now let us query each one to find out if they all have the same information.

For example with:

```
$ for ns in ns.rackspace.com.  ns2.rackspace.com. ns1.linode.com. ns2.linode.com. ns3.linode.com. ns4.linode.com. ns5.linode.com. ; do dig @$ns visitnc.com NS +noall +answer ; done
```

Editing the results for brevity, we have basically

`ns.rackspace.com.` and `ns2.rackspace.com.`  believing (giving back as answer because configured as such) that the authoritative nameservers for your domain are:

```
visitnc.com.        86400 IN NS ns.rackspace.com.
visitnc.com.        86400 IN NS ns2.rackspace.com.
```

that is themselves.

But at the same time each one of the 5 Linode ones are saying:

```
visitnc.com.        86400 IN NS ns4.linode.com.
visitnc.com.        86400 IN NS ns3.linode.com.
visitnc.com.        86400 IN NS ns1.linode.com.
visitnc.com.        86400 IN NS ns2.linode.com.
visitnc.com.        86400 IN NS ns5.linode.com.
```

that is themselves.

But as you can see, none of them reply the same thing as the parent, hence you have a "lame delegation" case, which is bad, and you need to fix that by deciding once for all which company is the handler of your DNS setup and then change of the parent zone to list only their nameservers.
You will need to go through your registrar (`whois visitnc.com | grep Registrar:` shows that it is *Network Solutions, LLC.*) to request this change.
This is the first thing you should do, and then wait a little, before attempting any other kind of troubleshooting.

Note this important point about the troubleshooting above: we always **explicitely** say which nameserver we query and we **never** query recursive nameservers at this step. When troubleshooting DNS issues you first need to make sure all authoritative nameservers are replying correctly and then only you can begin to search what is happening at recursive ones. Doing it differently will only lead you to spending more time following false hints.

As a side note you can see that the `SOA` records are very different, including for the serial.
Rackspace servers reply with:

```
visitnc.com.        300 IN SOA ns.rackspace.com. hostmaster.rackspace.com. (
                1527624042 ; serial
                3600       ; refresh (1 hour)
                300        ; retry (5 minutes)
                1814400    ; expire (3 weeks)
                300        ; minimum (5 minutes)
                )
```

Where Linode ones give:

```
visitnc.com.        86400 IN SOA ns1.linode.com. mklauss.outpostdesign.com. (
                2018052959 ; serial
                14400      ; refresh (4 hours)
                14400      ; retry (4 hours)
                1209600    ; expire (2 weeks)
                86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                )
```

Due to the latest set and specifically the `86400` as both TTL and negative TTL, you will need to wait at least this amount of seconds (aka 1 day) after having changed anything **and** seeing the parent authoritative nameservers showing the updated information.
Note that the parent TTL on NS records is twice this amount, so the pessimistic way will be to wait at least 48 hours after any change to start again checking things and troubleshooting what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Hi there.  Thank you for such a detailed and insightful response to the post.  I have switched the correct answer to yours as it is by far the most complete.  It ended up that the domain registrar was indeed having problems and was serving both sets of authoritative nameservers, despite several attempts to change it to a single set from their control panel.

Answer (score 4):

`whois visitnc.com` returns the following for the domain:

```
Name Server: NS1.LINODE.COM
Name Server: NS2.LINODE.COM
Name Server: NS3.LINODE.COM
Name Server: NS4.LINODE.COM
Name Server: NS5.LINODE.COM
Name Server: NS2.RACKSPACE.COM
Name Server: NS.RACKSPACE.COM
```

Check the nameserver settings at your registrar. Remove the Rackspace records if they're there. If they're not there, you'll need to ask the domain registrar why they're showing up in whois.

Comment: Thank you.  I wanted to rule out any possibility of misconfiguration on my end (as somebody who has access to Rackspace and Linode DNS services).

I do not have access to the registrar, and it was my understanding that the NS records were confirmed as being 100% Linode as of a few days ago, but I do not know for certain, and based on your suggestion I did notify those with access that they might want to ask NS what is going on.  We'll see what happens...

Comment: whois has not operational impact on name resolution and should NOT be used to troubleshoot DNS problems.

Answer (score 2):

There is a service called Zonemaster that checks DNS errors and gives you a report based on the available standards and best practices. Running your zone against it shows delegation and consistency errors, which are the source of your problems.

When you look up a hostname that ends in .com, your computer asks the .com nameservers where it can find the information for your domain. In this case, the .com nameservers have both the Rackspace and the Linode nameservers listed. But the Rackspace servers and the Linode servers aren't in sync with one another.

The persons in charge of the domain should look at https://zonemaster.net/test/9e6531748fa412d3 which shows all the errors, and work to get their domain removed from Rackspace.

Comment: Ultimately, all those delegation/consistency errors are because OP has two different vendors set up as authoritative nameservers. They'll go away if they remove Rackspace from the domain's nameservers.

Comment: @ceejayoz Clients using Rackspace's DNS servers will still get the wrong information.

Comment: *Maybe*, if Rackspace uses their public nameservers as internal DNS that takes precedence. I tend to doubt they're set up that way.

Comment: @ceejayoz In theory, they shouldn't be. And in theory there's no difference between theory and practice. In practice, however...

Comment: "When you look up a hostname that ends in .com, the first thing that happens is that your computer asks the .com nameservers where it can find the information for your domain. " if the cache is not cold, otherzise the first query would be to the root servers to both update the list of root servers and learn about the `.COM` authoritative nameservers.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Right; I missed fixing part of that as I edited a far too lengthy answer to restrict the answer to the issue at hand. I think I made it less wrong now.